# Error in initializing airflow.2.3.3 "Table 'airflow.ab_permission_id_seq' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, database, initialization, airflow

Freshly have installed apache-airflow 2.3.3 and have set the airflow.cfg pointing mysql

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow:airflow@<<apphost>>:<<port>>/airflow
```

Airflow DB check was successful

```
>airflow db check
{db.py:1605} INFO - Connection successful.
```

Upon db initialization getting below

```
>airflow db init

_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError) (MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'airflow.ab_permission_id_seq' doesn't exist")
[SQL: INSERT INTO ab_permission (id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)]
[parameters: [{'name': 'can_read'}]]
```

I have pointed to mysql database, but still during db initialize tries to execute a sequence and fails in initialization.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using MariaDB, which is not officially supported by Airflow. The list of supported db: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/prerequisites.html?highlight=mariadb

The official statement on MariaDB:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/24247